# ORM to the distinct values from a model based on the latest datetime field in Django

Tags: django, orm

Consider I have a model named History and it has data like this.

```
name       comment           date
----------------------------------
Jake    some comment     2017-06-20
John    some comment     2017-08-20
Jake    some comment     2017-06-21
Albert  some comment     2017-06-21
```

and from the above sample data, I want to get distinct data based on the datetime field. For example, the result should look like below from the above sample data.

```
name       comment           date
----------------------------------
John    some comment     2017-08-20
Jake    some comment     2017-06-21
Albert  some comment     2017-06-21
```

How can I write an ORM for this? can anyone please help me!

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct data based on datetime field"? Do you want the latest comment of each user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```
History.objects.order_by('name', '-date').distinct('name')
```